# Unintended horizontal movement of screen

Tags: android, css, html

If you open my page at http://goo.gl/68s0t (Please don't replace the link here as I don't want google to link this page to my site.) on an android phone and move your finger from left to right, you also move the content.

What is the cause for this and how do I make the content fit in horizontally so moving to the right and left with your finger does not cause movement of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the width of the container and `overflow: hidden` to force any content to cut off at that width. If you want to be able to scroll vertically, use `overflow-x: hidden` to only cut off horizontally.

Early versions of Android have sub-optimal CSS compatibility, so your best bet is testing it out on those devices with trial and error.